# Installing Q package for Python 2.7 on Win 64-bit

Tags: python-2.7, installation

I am trying to install the Q connection library for Python by Dan Nugent (https://github.com/nugend/q). However, I don't see any installer in the package. How should I properly install this package for Python 2.7 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a pure Python package you don't need to anything other than download all the `.py` files into their own directory. Either make it a subdirectory of the `lib\site-packages` directory in your Python installation, or a subdirectory of the project you want to use it.